# Cannot locate the panel for adjust the 'jitter'

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I seem to have lost the ability to adjust the size jitter - I keep getting just the size/hardness view.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you double click on the 'Shape Dynamics' it should bring up the panel with the Size Jitter in at the top - on your image shows Brush Tip Shape highlighted.

[image: jitter image]

[See Link](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/photoshop-brushes/brush-dynamics/shape-dynamics/)

Answer (score 1):

select brush panel
click on Shape dynamics
it will bringout Jitter Adjustments[image]